# How to assign a value from a list, to a variable, from a user input code

Tags: python-3.x

Let's say I have two lists A and B of prices, where each price corresponds to a code. Like A1 is $2.50, A2 is $3.50, etc.

The user inputs the codes of the items they want. From there I just need the prices of the items they selected assigned to variables and added together.

How do I set the inputed code to the respective cost if a more efficient way?

```
items = [str(x) for x in input("What items would you like?").split()]

item1 = items[0]
item2 = items[1]

A = [2.50, 3.50, 4.50, 5.00, 6.50]
B = [1.00, 1.50, 2.00, 2.50, 3.00]

if item1 == "A1":
    item1cost = A[0]
elif item1 == "A2":
    item1cost = A[1]
elif item1 == "A3":
    item1cost = A[2]
elif item1 == "A4":
    item1cost = A[3]
elif item1 == "A5":
    item1cost = A[4]

if item2 == "B1":
    item2cost = B[0]
elif item2 == "B2":
    item2cost = B[1]
elif item2 == "B3":
    item2cost = B[2]
elif item2 == "B4":
    item2cost = B[3]
elif item2 == "B5":
    item2cost = B[4]

print (item1cost + item2cost)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `dict` mapping item codes as the keys, and costs as the values. Here is an example how `dict` works :

```
a = {'A1': 2.5, 'B1': 1.0}
a['A1'] + a['B1']
# 3.5
```